# Using generators outside of a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Relatively new to python so please excuse the newbie question, but google isn't helpful at this time.

I have 100 very large xlsx files from which I need to extract the first row (specifically cell A2). I found this gem of a tool called openpyxl [which will iterate through my data files](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#openpyxl.reader.iter_worksheet.IterableWorksheet) without loading everything in memory. It uses a generaotor to get the relevant row on each call

The thing that I can't get is how to initialize a generator outside of a loop. Right now my code is:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = "merged01.xlsx", use_iterators= True)
sheetName = wb.get_sheet_names()
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = sheetName[0])
row = ws.iter_rows() #row is a generator
for cell in row:
    break
print (cell[1].internal_value) # A2
```

But there has to be a better way of doing this such as:

```
...
row = ws.iter_rows() #row is a generator
cell = row.first # line I'm trying to KISS
print (cell[1].internal_value) # A2
```

Comment: As a side note, you can probably replace your third and fourth lines with `ws = wb.get_active_sheet()` (the active sheet defaults to 0).

Comment: While you're at it, you can use `cell = ws.cell("A2")` and `cell.value` to get its value. If that's all you want, there's no need to iterate.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Noted, although a select worksheet number would be a nice tool to have

Comment: @PauloAlmeida regarding the second comment, that only works if you load everything in memory (which, at 300 MB/file, is not something I can do):...`"NotImplementedError: use 'iter_rows()' instead"`

Comment: I agree. I don't know if there's a better way to get worksheets by number, but it would definitely be nice. Regarding your latest comment, ok, that's a problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
cell = next(row)
```

The `next` function retrieves the next value from any iterator.

Comment: bugger... tried row.next(), but that returned an error... Lesson learned

Comment: @Rasman: That used to work, but they renamed the method to `__next__` in 3.x. (Don't call `__next__` directly, by the way.)

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next).

```
cell = next(row)
```